# What's the difference between these two strings in a PHP array?

Tags: php, drupal

This is a problem I'm having in a drupal theme, but the problem seems to be some esoteric PHP issue, so I thought I'd try to find an answer here.

The $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'] array is used to find template files. Right now it finds the template if I hard code the same value as seemingly already exists.

Logically it seems like same input should == same output, so I feel like the input must be somehow different between the two if one finds the template and the other does not.

So what could possibly be the difference between the two 'page__gallery' strings I'm appending to this array? I've tried rebuilding the string by splitting it and recombining it. I've tried doing a encoding comparison between the whole strings, and each character in the string. In every way they appear identical, but it only works if I manually type it.

```
$str2 = 'page__gallery';
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $str2; // if I comment this line out, it doesn't find the template.
print $str2; //output is page__gallery

$str1 = $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][3];
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $str1; // if I comment this line out, it finds the template still.
print $str1; //output is page__gallery

print $str1 == $str2; // 1
print $str1 === $str2; // 1
var_dump($str1) // Outputs: string(13) "page__gallery"
var_dump($str2) // Outputs: string(13) "page__gallery"
```

var_dump of `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` with the hard-coded string value:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(10) "page__node" [1]=> string(13) "page__node__%" [2]=> string(14) "page__node__96" [3]=> string(13) "page__gallery" [4]=> string(20) "page__drisco_gallery" [5]=> string(13) "page__gallery" }
```

var_dump of `$vars['theme_hook_suggestions']` with the same string as already exists re-appended:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(10) "page__node" [1]=> string(13) "page__node__%" [2]=> string(14) "page__node__96" [3]=> string(13) "page__gallery" [4]=> string(20) "page__drisco_gallery" [5]=> string(13) "page__gallery" }
```

First one works, second one does not.

Help!

Comment: Try `var_dump` instead of `print_r` and update.

Comment: Try using `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` as `var_dump()` will tell you the type of whatever is stored as well.

Answer (score 0):

print returns 1 always
http://php.net/manual/en/function.print.php

So this line does not test correctly

```
print $str1 === $str2; // 1
```

As suggested var_dump() is better choice.

Comment: It always returns 1, but it should still print 0 if that statement is false, right? I edited with var_dumps.

Comment: echo print 1==0; //prints 1, print 1==0; // nothing